# Call a function in JS file from drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have included a javascript in the module "myid" I've been developing in drupal by using this code:

```
function myid_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "js/myid.js");   
}
```

This is my Javascript file "myid.js":

```
function myid_js_start(){
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Below is the code that creates a button that invokes an alert function:

```
$form['add_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Take a picture',
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'myid_js_start()'),    
);
```

I dont know where did I go wrong. The button shows up but doesn't fire any alert function. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the proper drupal directory structures and everything is where it supposed to be then it could be you are setting the attributes[onclick] as 'myid_js_start()'. Try doing it like

```
$form['add_button'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Take a picture',
  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'myid_js_start'),    
);
```

Maybe that will solve it.

I don't have a drupal system setup at the moment to test your code. It could be something else but worth a try.

Comment: I tried editing my code by omitting "()", but still nothing's change. The page refreshes everytime I click the button and there's no alert dialog appeared.

Comment: Ok here's what you should do. First see if your onclick is being called  or not. Try `'#attributes' => array('onclick' => "alert('hello world'); return false;")`

Comment: hello world appears, but I want to call the function in my Java script file. Probably there's something wrong with my Javascript file path. Am I right?

Comment: I already figured it out, I just return false; in my script function. Anyways, why do we have to "return false" in my Java script function? Any rationale?

Comment: Buttons in HTML by default submit forms. I guess that could be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the `.js` file to the form itself using [`#attach`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#attached).

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "js/myid.js"),
);
```